# trying to do a linq query return on a sub query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am not even sure how to word the question, if anybody wants to suggest after reading I will update.

The problem from a business perspective is I need to know if any of the stops (deliverys) have had a file generated for them in the past.  When this file is generated a journal entry is created with a record type of 40 and a date along with a matching ID number.

I have a linq query in C# (6) Linq to entities.
I need a field in the return that either counts or just returns true if another query find anything.

Here is part of the query:

```
var stopDetails = (from d in dbContext.stop_details
                           join c in dbContext.customers on d.customer_id equals c.id
                           join name in dbContext.driver_details on d.assigned_driver_id equals name.ddp_driver_id
                           join journal in dbContext.stop_journals on d.id equals journal.stop_details_id
                           where (d.verified_ship_date >= startDate && d.verified_ship_date <= endDate)
                           select new
                           {
                               d.ship_date,
                               stopID = d.id,
                               d.verified_ship_date,
                               d.assigned_driver_id,
                               driverName = name.first_name + " " + name.last_name,
                               fullDriverInfo = d.assigned_driver_id + " - "+ name.first_name + " " + name.last_name,
                               d.cust_ref_1_BOL,
                               d.cust_ref_2_OrderNum,
                               d.cust_ref_3_stopID,
                               d.con_name,
                               d.con_address1,
                               d.con_address2
```

What I need to know is if there are any records in the stop_journal for each of the stops that contain a record_type of 45 and a dateTimeRef == the verified_ship_date.

If I cant figure it out in the front end like this I will probably just step through the datagrid (where the results are posted) and update each row that way.

so pseudo code would be something like:
for each row if there is a journal entry with the stop_details_id matching stopID And a dateTimeRef == verified_ship_date And a record_type of 40 then set the FoundFlag = true

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `.Any()` to do if exists, and then just put in your query inside your select:

```
FoundFlag = (from j2 in dbContext.stop_journals where j2.stop_details_id == d.id &&
             j2.dateTimeRef == d.verified_ship_date && j2.record_type == 40 select j2).Any()
```

Comment: Perfect -- thank you so much, I was getting lost in the code for some reason.